# Find the Laurent expansion of: $\frac{i}{z+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Find the Laurent expansion of: $$\frac{i}{z+i}$$

What should I do?

Do I need to times it by the complex conjugate? In that case I get:

$$\frac{i}{z+i}=\frac{iz+1}{z^2+1}$$ , I then tried to complete the square:

$$\frac{iz+1}{z^2+2z-2z+1}=\frac{iz+1}{(z+1)^2-2z}$$, which doesn't get me anywhere.
On the other hand if I keep it imaginary, I don't know any power series expansions to go with them.

Comment: About what point?

Comment: I don't know (I'm assuming it's $0$). I'm asked to show different series for $|z|<1 ,1< |z|<2, |z|>2$ , but I think I can do that once I know the Laurent expansion

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic at $0$ so Laurent series is just power series with radius of convergent$=1$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $\;\left|\frac zi\right|=|z|<1\;$ , then

$$\frac i{z+i}=\frac1{1+\frac zi}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{i^n}$$

or if $\;\left|\frac iz\right|=\frac1{|z|}<1\iff |z|>1\;$ , then

$$\frac i{z+i}=\frac iz\frac1{1+\frac iz}=\frac iz\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^ni^n}{z^n}$$

About the only complex pole, i.e. $\;z=-i\;$ , the series is pretty boring: it is $\;\frac i{z+i}\;$ .

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Can you explain why the series is $\frac{1}{z+i}$? Is there a rule that Laurent series about complex poles is itself?

Comment: @GRS Because that's all we have for a *power series* about the point $\;z=-i\;$ .